# What are the scenario `tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath` method get call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Can any one explain about `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` method life cycle. At what are the time this method get call.

Example while the first time a tableview is populated.

Other than this any time this method get called? When I call `reloadData` method, `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` method is not getting called. How can i make sure `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` method should get called when ever i call `reloadData` method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a breakpoint and see.

Comment: Please clarify. Does your `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` ever get called? Or is the problem that it is called sometimes but not when you call `reloadData`?

Comment: @rmaddy its getting called when first time table view gets loaded. but when i call `reloadData` methods its not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

Is is possible that you haven't assigned your ViewController to be the tableView's delegate?

Comment: i already assigned delegate object. but the issue was different.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the method gets called after calling reloadData. As Todd indicated, check that the delegate is assigned and that it remains assigned, e.g. after the first load maybe the delegate of the tableview is changed or set to nil.